# How can I change grub bootloader while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: bootloader, boot-repair, debian, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I have installed Debian 10 on my device which is loaded by grub boot loader, now I want to install Ubuntu minimal on my device, but when I want to boot my mini.iso, its installation won't load and I'll face grub boot loader!
I even tried deleting grub boot loader but it didn't work, and it will load again!
Grub is on UEFI boot type, I need to change my boot type to Legacy to be able to load my Ubuntu USB installer.

I will be glad if you can help me out of this.
Thanks.

Comment: It is highly recommended that you install multiple OSes in the same mode, UEFI  if Debian is in UEFI mode.  According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD , the mini-iso only does legacy, so they suggest using ubuntu-server. Your machine settings determine which mode a system boots -- provided both modes are present on your boot media.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for your response, So there is no way I could install mini-iso which does legacy on my device?

Comment: If you can boot the legacy install media, you can install, provided you have a compatible disk layout (if gpt partitioning, you need a bios-grub flagged partition for legacy)  But if Debian is in UEFI mode, you would need to switch boot modes to the preferred mode to select which OS to boot -- not convenient.

Comment: @ubfan1 I tried to install windows 10 from legacy boot mode, but it loaded grub boot loader again! I think my legacy boot is not work! I have to find a way to make it work I don't know how, If you know something about this I'll be gald if you help me more! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your machine's BIOS/UEFI settings determine how it boots.  Sometimes these settings are not very clear, like instead of "legacy" the term used is CMS (CSM?) for "compatibility mode". By the time grub shows up, that decision has been made, a boot has occurred and you cannot change the mode.

Comment: I do not think mini installer has UEFI mode. Those that want a mini install in UEFI mode install the server version, but then do not choose any server apps with tasksel. You may be able to convert mini to boot in UEFI mode. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2419997&p=13862419#post13862419